# passing values from subclass of a subclass in java

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract

I have this code for example, i have a super abstract class animal and a abstract subclass bird, and a subclass of bird AmericanRobin, i want to fill data in american robin to create the object bird from animal but i don't know how to do it because i want to create another subclass of bird called Domestic canary and pass the values from his constructor to his superclass constructor to create an object, any advice??

```
public abstract class Animal {// SuperClass animal

    private String Kind,Appearance;

    Animal(String Kind,String Appearance) {
        this.Kind = Kind;
        this.Appearance = Appearance;
    }

    public abstract void eat();
    public abstract void move();

    @Override public String toString() {
        return "("+Kind+","+Appearance+")";
    }

    public abstract class Bird extends Animal {//SubClass of superClass Animal 

        Bird(String Kind, String Appearance) {
            super(Kind, Appearance);
        }

        @Override public void eat() {

            System.out.println("Eats seeds and insects");
        }

        @Override public void move() {
            System.out.println("Flies throught the air");
        }
    }

    public  abstract class Fish extends Animal{//SubClass of SuperClass Animal

        Fish(String Kind, String Appearance){
            super(Kind,Appearance);
        }

        @Override public void eat() {
            System.out.println("Eats krill, algae and insects");
        }

        @Override public void move() {
            System.out.println("Swims throught the water");
        }
    }

    //== Here the pain begins ==
    public class AmericanRobin extends Bird    {

        AmericanRobin(String Kind, String Appearance) {
            super(Kind, Appearance);
        }            
    }

    public class DomesticCanary extends Bird{

        DomesticCanary(String Kind, String Appearance) {
            super(Kind, Appearance);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats not working for you, please explain. What errors do you get or what is expected vs actual output for you.

Comment: Creating as many classes as there are birds is an overkill. You should create  `Animal americanCan=new Bird("American Canary","Brownish may be")` and `Animal domesticCan=new Bird("Domestic Canary", "Very colourful")` etc... if need be add another data member/variable  say  `genus` may be(alongside `kind` and `appearance`)

Comment: well this is a exercise i have an abstract main clase and other abstract class father of kind of animal, animal ->bird and fish-> species of bird and fish.

Model part of an animal hierarchy by declaring Animal, Bird, Fish,
AmericanRobin, DomesticCanary, RainbowTrout, and SockeyeSalmon
classes:

Answer (score 0):

1. Please rename variables to distinguish them from class names. `kind` and `appearance` are better names.
2. To test your inheritance structure, try creating an instance of subclass and call a method that it inherits, in your case:

   ```
   AmericanRobin americanRobin = new AmericanRobin("kind","appearance");
   System.out.println(americanRobin.toString()); // inherited from Animal
   ```

Comment: look i understand but the logic is this... i have a main abstract class call animal with 2 strings kind and appareance, then i have another abstract class called bird and fish and finally the species class called american robin and domestic canary this have and empy values in their constructors the idea is to pass these argumenes like this statement:

SockeyeSalmon is public, extends Fish, and declares a public
noargument constructor that passes "sockeyesalmon" and "bright
red with a green head" to its superclass constructor. 

this is exercise of inheritance

Comment: so the son class SockeyeSalmon pass his arguments by his constructor to his superclass fish constructor (fish pases to animal) and i use getKind and apareance string values to do this in this example 

public class SockeyeSalmon extends Fish{
  SockeyeSalmon(String Kind, String Appearance){
   super(Kind,Appearance);
  }
  
  public String getKind() {
   return"SockeyeSalmon";
  }
  
  public String getAppearance() {
   return"Description";
  }
 }